# Use of header files consisting only on #include directives?

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I am new to C++ and I'm currently reading some code that has multiple header files of the form:

```
#include <some standard library>
#include <some standard library>
...


#include <some third party library header>
#include <some third party library header>
...

#include <some internal header files>
#include <some internal header files>
...
```

and **nothing else**. I don't really understand the use of these files, or why they are structured this way, since I thought that header files carried class declarations that basically consist on the interface that other code uses to access an object file. I think the programmer may have wanted to "package" all the headers inside one big header and just include that. Is this a good idea or is it better to avoid these "include only" headers?

Comment: Is this `stdafx.h`?

Comment: It's so that users only have to include that one header file instead of all of those other ones.

Comment: @Micheal So you include a load of headers you probably don't need - way to go.

Comment: @Justin No, this is not stdafx.h.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is [precompiled headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).
Instead of including all headers in all compilation units, only one file is included which, after the first parse it's cached. Then, compilation of the rest of the units for the current or the next builds is faster.

Hence the big PCH files you see in Visual Studio, for example. Typical setup is stdafx.h which is included in all compilation units, where the first one produces the precompiled header, the others reuse it.